# Compare values from each JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `each()` which collects all checked checkboxes with parameter `data-is-rate = 1`

```
 $('input[data-is-rate="1"]:checked').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
 });
```

From this, I'm getting every `data-id`

```
111
222
333
```

So is there any way to compare them? The IDs are not unique and can be the same and I need to check.

So if `data-id` recurs, it should return an error.

For example, if the output is like this, it should return an error.

```
111
222
111
```

If the output is like this, there should be no error because the values are unique

```
111
222
333
```

How can I compare these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this maybe helps, when error do what ever needs to be done...

```js
var ids = [];
$('input[data-is-rate="1"]:checked').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  
  if(ids.includes($(this).attr('data-id'))) {
      console.log(' E R R O R !');
  }
  
  ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="111" checked="checked">111
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="111" checked="checked">111
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="222" checked="checked">222
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="333" checked="checked">333
```

if `data-id="111"` is not checked twice there is no error

```js
var ids = [];
$('input[data-is-rate="1"]:checked').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  
  if(ids.includes($(this).attr('data-id'))) {
      console.log(' E R R O R !');
  }
  
  ids.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="111" checked="checked">111
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="111" >111
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="222" checked="checked">222
<input data-is-rate="1" type="checkbox" data-id="333" checked="checked">333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```js
var unique = {};
$('input[data-is-rate="1"]:checked').each(function(){
    if (unique[$(this).attr('data-id')]) {
        // Duplicate data-id, handle error
        alert('Duplicate data-id' + $(this).attr('data-id'));
    } else {
        unique[$(this).attr('data-id')] = 1;
    }
});
```